# Is it possible to use < & > for an example with generics in C# doc comments?

Tags: c#, documentation, comments

Anyone who has ever tried writing an example for some generic code inside
of a documentation comment knows it can be rather hard if you dont want 
them to be confused with tags. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Some of the MSDN docs use parentheses (e.g., `List(T)`). Just a guess, but maybe that's how it's done?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure In vs2013 &gt; and &lt; work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use CDATA if you have a bigger multi-line example and you don't want to escape each < > & and ". The comment will be more readable as well. For example:

```
/// <code><![CDATA[
///    List<int> mylist;
/// ]]></code>
```

Comment: Way more readable multi-line comments, nice! Do you know if there's a way to get CDATA `<summary>` and `<param>` comments to show up via IntelliSense too?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use `&lt;` and `&gt;`, since C# doc comments are XML.

Comment: Yes, I've just confirmed that this works as expected.